# Work and Energy question, using Tension

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, spring, string

[image]

[image]

Given this image, $2$ objects are connected via a spring (its mass is negligible)
The spring constant is $k$ and that is all that is given.. mass of $A$ is just $m_A$ etc.. and $g \approx 9.8 \frac{m}{s^2}$ (on Earth)
I need to find the maximum displacement ("stretching") of the spring ($L$)
I tried to draw the forces (Positive Y points  down, positive X points to the right):

For mass $B$:
$$M_b g - T = (M_a + M_b)a$$

For mass $A$:
$$T - f_{\text{spring}} = M_a a$$

Now I add these two equations and substitute $f_{\text{spring}} = k \cdot L$ :

$$ L = \frac{M_b g - a(2M_a + M_b)}{k}$$

This is a MCQ and none of the answers have $a$ in them... what have I done wrong? I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose if the block A is displaced by L , then the block b should also move down by L as length of the string is constant and the string is in extensible.

Now if the spring and block A is extended  by L i.e their PE is increased  $\frac{KL^2}{2}$ which is equal to decrease (as moved down) in gravitational potential energy of block A $m_bgL$

After equating these two, we get $L=\frac{2m_bg}{k}$

Comment: Wow the string tension really confused me.. Thank you so much!!